# PWM 3.3 V signal to switch (on/off) 24 V light load at 8 MHz? It's doable? Bipolar? MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, pwm, switching

For a project, I would need to drive a 10 pF capacitive load with a 24 V PWM signal with a 8 MHz.

I have already done power MOSFET switching in the past for DC/DC converters but the frequency were very low (400 kHz) compared to 8 MHz.

Do you think this is doable? And if yes what kind of transistor is the more suited for this kind of frequency?

Regards.

Comment: With somewhat sharpish 24 V square wave into 10 pF, you are looking at about 150 mA peak for your transistor. Certainly doable with a MOSFET, but you need good gate drive and low input capacitance on your MOSFET of choice. Please simulate it with real components and parasitics.

Comment: What waveform is required? Fixed amplitude and frequency, or variable over what range(s)?

Comment: What's "light load"? 10mA? 10A? "light" is relative. More importantly _why_ does it _have_ to be 8MHz? What hardware sets this requirement?

Comment: You might want to look into a GaN FET with an integrated driver.  That would solve a lot of issues you might have with the driver and layout, as well as providing a very high-speed switch.  However, you'll probably generate a lot of EMI however you do it.